# Identifying and recording fields that have been updated

Tags: entities

I need to keep a record of fields that have been updated since some arbitrary point in time.  My initial approach was to use hook_entity_update() and compare the fields in the updated entity with those stored in $entity->original.  Any fields that didn't match were recorded in a separate table for future reference.

Unfortunately I then discovered that my content type contained fields organised into field collections.  It seems that field collections are stored as a single field which references independent entities.  Of course this reference doesn't change even when the field collection entity itself does.  Even if I were to load the field collection entity from within my update hook I wouldn't know whether it had changed or not.

So I'm stumped.

Would this be possible via some other mechanism ?  My first thought is hooking into the form submission but I'd need some pointeers on how to use From API to accomplish this.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Why don't you use [revisions](https://drupal.org/node/320614).